# How to redirect nginx based on sub path?

Tags: nginx, jenkins, grafana

I have grafana and jenkins running on same azure vm.
For jenkins: http://localhost:8080
For grafana: http://localhost:3000

I thought to set nginx in such a way.
customdomain.com/grafana should go to http://localhost:3000
customdomain.com/jenkins or customdomain.com should go to http://localhost:8080

But even /grafana is going to jenkins only.

How to fix that?

The, default config file for mapping in nginx.

```
 location /grafana {
                include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
                proxy_pass          http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_read_timeout  60s;
        # Fix the "It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
        # Make sure the domain name is correct
                #proxy_redirect      http://localhost:3000 https://customdomain.com;
        }

        location / {
                include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
                proxy_pass          http://localhost:8080;
                proxy_read_timeout  60s;
        # Fix the "It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
        # Make sure the domain name is correct
                proxy_redirect      http://localhost:8080 https://customdomain.com;
        }
```

Comment: Please add output of `curl -v` when you visit `/grafana` URL.

Comment: Maybe you need `proxy_redirect off;` for the /grafana location